# Base de datos demora en entregar la respuesta a Java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, cloud

les comento he desarrollado un software con java y estoy consumiendo una base de datos en la nube mysql, este servicio se llama hostinger, mi problema es que lleva tiempo entregar los datos de la base de datos al software, un ejemplo ingreso un jframe y tengo dos comboBox que hacen 2 consultas, la demora en cargar todo el jframe promedio tarda promedio , 5 segundos he estado investigando es un problema de latencia de red, pero aun así creo que debe haber alguna solución para reducir ese tiempo, espero su ayuda y espero sus comentarios

Comment: Una solución es almacenar los datos en cache así solo demorarar la primera vez y las siguientes veces será más rápido

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]: ten en cuenta que tu pregunta actualmente es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, por lo tanto podría terminar cerrada.

Comment: ¿Cuántos datos muestras? ¿Cuántos datos tiene la tabla o tablas que consultas? ¿Cuánto demora la ejecución de la pura consulta?

Comment: christian me comentaste uso de cache , bueno creo que seria la mejor opcion , alvaro C. me comentas de datos - no creo que tenga que ver cuantos datos mostrar la verdad , pero aun asi obtengo promedio 109 filas ,   la ejecucion en el mismo CLI que mayormente trabajo demora promedio promedio 0.20 sec , pero al llamar desde java demora aprox cada consulta 2 segundos